# Android app crashes when trying to set a click listener on ImageButton in Fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, nullpointerexception, imagebutton

Trying to set onClickListener on ImageButton in a fragment (SessionsFragment.java) and I keep getting a null pointer exception. Tried all different solutions and still getting the same error. The button resides in an item in ExpandableListView hence why I've added the list_item.xml. Seen a few comments saying that it's null because it's not in the main activity or something along those lines. Regardless, how can I overcome this?

SessionsFragment.java

```
public class SessionsFragment extends Fragment {

ExpandableListAdapter expandableListAdapter;
ExpandableListView expandableListView;
List<String> listDataHeader;
HashMap<String, List<String>> listDataChild;
ImageButton addButton;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_sessions, container, false);

    // Get the ListView
    expandableListView = view.findViewById(R.id.sessionsExpandableListView);

    // Prepare the list data
    prepareListData();

    expandableListAdapter = new ExpandableListAdapter(getContext(), listDataHeader, listDataChild);

    // Set the list adapter and expand lists by default
    expandableListView.setAdapter(expandableListAdapter);
    expandableListView.expandGroup(0);

    // Get button values
    addButton = view.findViewById(R.id.addButton);
    addButton.setOnClickListener(new ImageButton.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Session added", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });

    return view;
}
```

list_item.xml

```
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="55dp">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/listItem"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    android:paddingTop="5dp"
    android:paddingBottom="5dp" />
    <!--android:paddingLeft="?android:attr/expandableListPreferredChildPaddingLeft"/>-->

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/addButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_add_black_24dp"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />
```

Logcat

> 04-25 15:12:04.053 11894-11901/? E/zygote64: Failed sending reply to
>   debugger: Broken pipe
>       04-25 15:12:04.578 11894-11894/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                          Process: com.example.android.engineeringweek, PID: 11894
>                                                          java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
>   ComponentInfo{com.example.android.engineeringweek/com.example.android.engineeringweek.SessionsActivity}:
>   java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void
>   android.widget.ImageButton.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)'
>   on a null object reference
>                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2946)
>                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3046)
>                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
>                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1688)
>                                                              at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
>                                                              at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
>                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6809)
>                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                              at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
>                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
>                                                           Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void
>   android.widget.ImageButton.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)'
>   on a null object reference
>                                                              at com.example.android.engineeringweek.SessionsFragment.onCreateView(SessionsFragment.java:47)
>                                                              at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2354)
>                                                              at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1419)
>                                                              at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManager.java:1740)
>                                                              at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1809)
>                                                              at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.executeOps(BackStackRecord.java:799)
>                                                              at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOps(FragmentManager.java:2580)
>                                                              at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2367)
>                                                              at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:2322)
>                                                              at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:2229)
>                                                              at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchStateChange(FragmentManager.java:3221)
>                                                              at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentManager.java:3171)
>                                                              at android.support.v4.app.FragmentController.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentController.java:192)
>                                                              at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:560)
>                                                              at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.onStart(AppCompatActivity.java:177)
>                                                              at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1412)
>                                                              at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:7015)
>                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2909)

**Edit**

ExpandableListAdapter.java

```
public class ExpandableListAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {
    private Context _context;
    private List<String> _listDataHeader;
    private HashMap<String, List<String>> _listDataChild;

    public ExpandableListAdapter(Context context, List<String> listDataHeader, HashMap<String, List<String>> listDataChild) {
        this._context = context;
        this._listDataHeader = listDataHeader;
        this._listDataChild = listDataChild;
    }

    @Override
    public int getGroupCount() {
        return this._listDataHeader.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
        return this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
        return groupPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        String headerTitle = (String) getGroup(groupPosition);
        if(convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) this._context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_group, null);
        }

        TextView listHeader = convertView.findViewById(R.id.listHeader);
        listHeader.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
        listHeader.setText(headerTitle);

        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return this._listDataChild.get(this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition)).get(childPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return childPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public View getChildView(int groupPosition, final int childPosition, boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        final String childText = (String) getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);

        if(convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) this._context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
        }

        TextView textListChild = convertView.findViewById(R.id.listItem);

        textListChild.setText(childText);

        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
        return this._listDataChild.get(this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition)).size();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isChildSelectable(int i, int i1) {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasStableIds() {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it).

Comment: Looks like `R.id.addButton` is not part of `R.layout.fragment_sessions`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems your findViewById can't find the id addButton.
After looking through your code I found you are inflating R.layout.fragment_sessions as your view, but searching for an id contained in your listitem.

When you want to add a clicklistener to a list item, you need to do this in your adapter class when creating/binding the viewholder.

Comment: So I have an ExpandableListAdapter class (will update post to include it), would I move the clicklistener code in my Fragment class to the getChildView method?

Comment: NO you need to move it to the expandable list view adapter where you should define the listener

Comment: Yeah I've added the adapter to my post but where do I define the listener is what I'm asking

Comment: Went ahead and added it to the getChildView method in my custom adapter class and this works

Comment: Correct, adding it to your getChildView Method is the way to go! I would've helped you earlier, but I was already offline, sorry. But I'm glad you made it work :)